# Will GAE fetchAsync outlive a request?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Many of GAE Java's threading functions don't outlive the user request. Can URL Fetch's [fetchAsync](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService.html#fetchAsync-java.net.URL-) in Java outlive the user's request? (Or put another way, still runs if it hasn't completed even if we have responded to the user's request).

Comment: My experience in python is no. The async operations get aborted. For example, if I try to add a task to the taskqueue, and if i dont wait for the async op to return, the task won't end up making it to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested fetchAsync in Java on GAE Standard and I can confirm that no response will be provided to the user until the fetchAsync has completed "building" the Future representation. Therefore, to answer your question, the fetchAsync will complete and only then will the user get a response.